# Why does a string cause entire pandas DataFrame to be non-numerical?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

If I create a pandas DataFrame using numerical values, this is reflected in the DataFrame. However, if the first element is a string, i.e. `'a'`, the entire DataFrame goes grey and all numbers in it are converted to strings, i.e. `3` becomes `'3'`. Why and how to retain datatype diversity?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

AA= pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([1,2,3]))
AA2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(['a','b',3]))
```

The output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is is use `np.asarray(['a','b',3]` all data are converting to strings, objects.

```
AA2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(['a','b',3]))
print (AA2.dtypes)
0    object
dtype: object

print (AA2[0].apply(lambda x: type(x)))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

If pass list get mixed data - numeric with strings:

```
AA2 = pd.DataFrame(['a','b',3])

print (AA2.dtypes)
0    object
dtype: object

print (AA2[0].apply(lambda x: type(x)))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'int'>
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

But working with mixed values is problemtic, most numeric operations failed, so the best is avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to do that. If you need some numbers having special meaning within a column, use a constant value reserved for that meaning instead :

```
NumberA = 1001
NumberB = 1002
```

Then you can do :

```
np.asarray([NumberA, NumberB, 3]
```

Anyway, it will be difficult to compute mathematic operations using such a set of values but, at least, you'll keep it fully numeric.

Comment: if i ever need to do math, i can just call the numerical column by itself `AA2.column_name_for_3`. I wouldn't work on the entire DataFrame